# Two 'prstat' commands are started when called from from 'os.system' call of python

Tags: python, shell, solaris

I am writing one python script to monitor the process.
I have `prstat` command to get the details of the process.

I have written the following code:

```
        #!/usr/bin/python
        import os,sys,re,time
        import subprocess
        def daemonize():
                pid = os.fork();
                if (pid < 0):
                        print "Forking error... exiting..."
                        sys.exit();
                if (pid > 0):
                        sys.exit()
                else:
                        print "Forking 1 success..."
                        pid = os.fork()
                        if (pid < 0):
                                print "Forking 2 error... exiting..."
                                sys.exit();
                        if (pid > 0):
                                sys.exit();
                print "Forking 2 success..."
        daemonize ()

    proc=subprocess.Popen('ps -ae | grep bulk', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.P
    IPE, )                                        //process bulk fork new process p1
    output=proc.communicate()[0]
    pid = output.split()                          // pid= pid of the process 'bulk' 
    proc=subprocess.Popen('pgrep -P ' +str(pid[0])+'', shell=True, stdout=subpr
    ocess.PIPE, )
    groovy_proc =proc.communicate()[0]            // groovy_proc -pchild process of 'bulk' need to be monitor
    os.system('prstat -p '+str(groovy_proc)+' -a -s size 2 5 >> /root/perf-stats/perf-logs/prstat.txt &') #TODO: two 'prstat' processes started,why?
```

When I run this script, I can see two `prstat` command running as

1. `sh -c prstat -p xxxx -a -s size`   as I have given in the python script
2. `prstat -p xxxx`

when I ran above code with  `os.system('prstat -p xxxx -a -s size 2 5 >> /root/perf-stats/perf-logs/prstat.txt &')` then I get the only `prstat -p xxxx -a -s size` command.

So adding `str(groovy_proc)` mess the script. What's going wrong here?

So here why this command 2 is present. Why `sh -c` option came here?

Comment: That first one is not a `prstat` command. It's a `sh` command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one prstat command running which is #2, the `sh -c ..` process is the shell that Python uses to run your command.

Edit:

`groovy_str` is likely to have a trailing newline.

Comment: command #! which I am trying to get without "sh -c" option. BWhen I hard code the pid value, then it works, but adding pid in variable groovy_proc, creates two procedures